# journalctl shows removed iptables logs

Tags: logging, iptables, systemd, rsyslog

Im logging a lot with iptables and to put my logs in a separate file I have put a couple rules in /etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf

```
:msg, startswith, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
:msg, regex, "^\[ *[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\] iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

This removes the logs from /var/log/{kern.log,daemon.log,messages} but when I issue journalctl -xe all the iptables logs show up there - so what file does journalctl read from and how can I remove the iptables logs from it?

Comment: I feel this might be more appropriate on serverfault.com or superuser.com .

Comment: Is it possible to move the question? Or do I need to delete this and create a new at serverfault/superuser?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when using LOG as target in iptables the dmesg still gets filled up even when rsyslog deletes from kern.log etc. journalctl -xe shows this dmesg text. Seems like using ulog is the only way:

```
apt-get install ulogd2
```

On debian testing this auto-created systemd unit file and configuration file.

Then I used iptables rules like:

```
iptables -N LOG_DROP
iptables -A LOG_DROP -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 10 -j NFLOG --nflog-group 0 --nflog-prefix "DROP "
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set -m comment --comment "Limit SSH IN" # add ip to recent list with --set.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j LOG_DROP -m comment --comment "Limit SSH IN"
```

And voila, all logs are in the logfile at /var/log/ulog/syslogemu.log